# How to fix all element position while changing width of select element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below code for two select element in a table but the first element affecting second element position .
  How to fix the position when width of select element changed onmouseover and onmouseout

to run visit http://jsfiddle.net/1k03tvmu/3/

Please help me out!!!

```
   <table>
   <tr>                            
     <td valign="top"><strong style="color: #3265a6">Area:&nbsp;</strong></td>
     <td class="content">
       <select style='FONT-SIZE: 9pt;width: 100px;' class="txtbox" id="hotelId_" size="5" multiple>
              <option value="All">Something</option>
       </select>
       <select style='FONT-SIZE: 9pt;width: 100px;' class="txtbox" id="Id" size="5" multiple>
               <option value="All">Something</option>
       </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
 element = document.getElementById('hotelId_');
 element.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
 var maxWidth = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
 if (element.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
   maxWidth = element.options[i].text.length;
 }
 }
 element.style.width = maxWidth * 27 + "px"; 
 });

element.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
var maxWidth = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
if (element.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
    maxWidth = element.options[i].text.length;
}
}
element.style.width = maxWidth * 7 + "px"; });
```

Comment: Don't you know that DOM elements need to have unique id ?!

Comment: "*but it changing the position of element*" - what is this 'it' of which you speak?

Comment: Yes i have changed that but same problem.

Comment: which is the wrong behavior?

Comment: @faby >> onmouseover/onmouseout first element width should increase/decrease and second element position should fixed but first element affecting position of second one.

Comment: @SudhansuSekharNayak do you want the tds elements in differents rows?

Comment: @faby yes both should be in one row and within two different tds

Comment: @David Thomas yes i have changed 'it' of which i speak and onmouseover/onmouseout first element width should increase/decrease and second element position should fixed but first element affecting position of second one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65623/discussion-between-sudhansu-sekhar-nayak-and-faby).

Comment: @SudhansuSekharNayak I've updated my answer. Let me know if it is what you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two elements with the same id `hotelId_` that is not correct.

then you use this Id to get elements from javascript

```
element = document.getElementById('hotelId_');
```

try assigning two differents ids and pass the id to the function that edit the html

**update**

try removing `td.content{width: 1000px; }`

from css

**Update 2**

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1k03tvmu/43/) fiddle

now it works as you expected, just change position relative to absolute when changing the width

```
element = document.getElementById('hotelId_');
element.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
var maxWidth = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (element.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
       maxWidth = element.options[i].text.length;
   }
}
element.style.width = maxWidth * 27 + "px"; 
    element.style.position="absolute";
});

element.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
var maxWidth = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (element.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = element.options[i].text.length;
    }
}
    element.style.width = maxWidth * 7 + "px"; 
    element.style.position="relative";
});
```

Comment: Yes I have changed that.

Comment: Yes i removed td.content but second element moved to next row.I want both should be in same row.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If you want all tds in the same row and you change the width of the first one the second automatically slide on the right. Could you paint what you want?

Comment: Thanks faby thanks a lot for your guide.Thanks for sharing fiddle.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `table` does not have a width defined, so it is trying to render within the width of the browser, but the td width is greater, so it adjusts in strange ways.

If the first cell is 100px and the second is 1000px, fix the table to `width:1100px;` and this should stop it jumping around (note I have not fixed your invalid ids):

```
table { border: 1px solid; width:1100px; }

tr { border: 1px solid; }

td { width: 100px; position: relative; }
td.content{ width: 1000px; }
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1k03tvmu/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1k03tvmu/3/

removed the row border and changed it to table cell - not sure if that really done anything

```
td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

gave the label cell a specific class

```
.label{ width: 100px;}
```

gave the select boxes a specific width

```
select{ width: 100px;}
```

everything seems to respond as it should!